# Auto-fill only certain fields in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

How do I get Google Chrome to only auto-fill for certain fields, certain sites, and be specific to site?

I just double-clicked in the Super User search box and I see things listed that I never entered in there. I've only entered them into Google search.

Clearly it can distinguish between a pair of user/pass combo fields. And a search box because I never see it mixing those together.  It would be good if it could be set per site.

Comment: I think it's an all or nothing switch.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't present such options to the user.

---

Thinking about it,   *perhaps* you can use LastPass Chrome extension to auto-fill selective fields for selective sites

Comment: Does FF? if so what Ext?

Comment: I don't use FF, can't comment. As far as Chrome *perhaps* you can use LastPass Chrome extension to auto-fill selective fields for selective sites